# Which look up rule prevents the compiler from finding the function?

Tags: c++

```
void Foo(int i)
{
}
struct Bar
{
    static void Foo() { Foo(1); }
};
```

The above code does not compile. It cannot find `Foo(int)`. Why? I know it has to do with having the same function name, but did not get further understanding the problem.

Why do I need a qualified lookup?

Comment: Look up stop at class scope as it found one matching function name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From 3.4.1 (emphasis mine)

> In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the
>   respective categories; **name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name**. If no declaration is
>   found, the program is ill-formed.

In this particular case the first scope to be searched is the function local scope. Foo is not found there. Then comes the class scope. Since the name Foo is found in it, the name lookup stops there and the other Foo does not participate in overload resolution at all.

Comment: It should be mentioned that [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) also occurs for unqualified lookup in some cases, even if a declaration was found without ADL (although not OP's exact case)

Answer (score 18):

If a function in a particular namespace shares the same name as one in a global namespace, then the one in the global namespace is not found.

Unfortunately the C++ standard does not allow you to bring in the global namespace into the current one with an appropriate `using` statement, although you can use `using ::Foo;` to pull in that particular function:

```
void Foo(char)
{
}

struct Bar
{
    static void Foo(double) { }
    static void Foo() {
        using ::Foo;
        Foo('c'); // correct overload is found since ::Foo is pulled into scope
        Foo(3.0);
    }
};
```

Otherwise you need to use the scope resolution operator to find the global function:

```
struct Bar
{
    static void Foo() { ::Foo(1); }
};
```

Comment: Well, [one can pull that particular name](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/710ef3787ff67c7e), and use unqualified lookup from that point on

Comment: @StoryTeller: Absolutely! and have pinched that.

Comment: Ahem, glad to have helped. But it's ill-formed at class-scope. Have to be inside a member function. It's why the example I linked to is more verbose than the OP's. To demonstrate when it's not just an extra line. You can pinch that as well if you'd like :)

Comment: Time to Wiki this I think!

Comment: @Bathsheba: How with the help of `using::Foo;`  the global function can be pulled? Could you please refer some documentation or explain the concepts a little more?

Comment: @skm - It's known as a [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration). Old as C++ itself, but many a tutorial skim it for some reason.... Come to think of it, namespaces in general aren't given their due respect in most tutorials, and those are damn useful.

Comment: Great answer, though i accepted the other one since it's more precise why it does not work.
"as one in a global namespace" should be "as in a parent namespace" or similiar. Helpful explanations, thanks guys

Comment: This is a wiki answer, so anyone should feel equally empowered to edit it.